# Switching between external user controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

for a signage application to be built. I am looking for a way to load external user controls. I keep getting stuck on the fact that the usercontrol must be in the same solution.

I am looking for a way to work with a direct link such as: "C: \ project \ usercontrols \ control1.cs

I hope you can help me

Comment: It would help to mention which framework you are using. WinForms, WebForms and WPF all have UserControls.

Comment: And they all can use UserControls from libraries.

Comment: sorry i forgot i am using winforms and framwork 4.0

Comment: @j-pee: Now what exactly do you mean by "external"? For all we know oyu try to add HTML elements to a Windows Form and that does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Christopher no I am trying to make standard user control. in another solution. so that my main application can continue to run and one by one can call up all user controls in a folder.

Comment: @j-pee I still can not parse what you are trying to do, so I am going to asume this is a XY Problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem | At that point the only question is: What is the problem you try to solve with "that thing you are trying to do"?

Comment: When you build a UserControl, it generates a `dll`. Add a refence to this component in another Solution: `References -> Add Reference -> Browse`. Find the `dll`, possibly built as Release, and add it to the Project that needs it.

Comment: Another option is to add the component using the code files. Use the `Project -> Add -> Existing Item` tool, then decide if you want to copy the files (normal `Add` button) or link the code files (`Add as Link` alternative mode). If the latter is used, the files won't be copied. Any modification to the UserControl performed in its project are reflected in the Project that links it. While this can be useful for code libraries, it can have undesired result when linking a component. In any case, you'll find the UC in the Toolbox.

Comment: I think you need [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/).

Comment: Your question is as follows: How to support add-ins using reflection? Right? Read CLR via C# book by Jeffrey Richter. In one of the chapters describes how to make an addin.

Comment: thanks for all suggestions. I will see tomorrow what works for me. and @Alexander Petrov I will see if I can get the book.